# ajax framework should I go for extjs or raxan?

Tags: jquery, ajax, frameworks, extjs

jquery- Definitely a great choice for DOM manipulation, and have lot of libraries.

extjs 3.0- http://www.extjs.com
they mentioned many big companies also using it. I seen their interface all great!

raxan framework- http://raxanpdi.com
Guys, any idea on this? Sounds good too.

YUI? I heard that YUI is less troublesome than extjs, more stable in event calling and better documentation.

I'm going to develop a php application.

Definitely jquery is a must.

Regarding extjs and raxan, guys what do you think?

Can give me some comment on its 
1. performance
2. code flexibility
3. whether it's your favorite, and whether it will become a trend in future?
4. whether can easily combine with cakephp?

Jquery is becoming a trend now, as you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard of Raxan.  It might be good, but it's still in beta and has fewer than 100 posts in its *entire* forum (http://raxanpdi.com/forum/).  If you're doing something serious, I might give that one a little more time to mature.

"I heard that YUI is less troublesome than extjs, more stable in event calling and better documentation."

I'd be curious to hear the evidence for that statement.  I won't knock YUI -- it's a good framework -- but Ext is stable and has great docs (full disclosure: I used to be part of the Ext team).  jQuery and Ext JS are apples and oranges.  Ext **Core** compares to jQuery, but then Ext JS contains an entire GUI suite in addition to the core library.  There is a UI project for jQuery, but it still doesn't really target the full range of components that Ext JS supports.  YUI and Dojo would be more in that league.

It really depends on what you need.  All the frameworks listed (except maybe Raxan?) are mature, proven and popular libraries.

Answer (score 1):

On my experience I am working with ExtJS since 1 year, what I like the most about it

- Really good documentation
- Good forum
- clean code
- really desktop look like component
- almost all the component you really need
- clean coding style.

If you are doing some website and you want to add some bits and piece of Ajax, ext-core is also really great. If you want to code a full CMS/EC system the framework.

Plus they are coming with a interface designer which is really great, we don't know if it's gonna be free but at least look promising.

For me but that's only my opinion ExtJS is the best around now

I am also looking into to JQuery now and used to watch Dojo when Zend made the partnership, those two are cool but I still prefer ExtJS.

Answer (score 1):

Hands down ExtJS would be my choice. I've worked with Prototype/scriptaculous, JQuery (didn't enjoy that), and Dojo. When I discovered ExtJS, I was so impressed I even converted an entire project from Dojo to it. Besides the fact its stable, well written and (very) well documented, looks excellent and is snappy fast - besides all that, the winning feature of ExtJs is that its developers are obviously considerate people who like to help others. They designed an API that the best definition I can give it is 'considerate'. It works for you , not against  you. 
Harel

Answer (score 1):

A few years back, I was working on a project using Prototype and Scriptaculous.  The customer was willing to allow changes (several) in our UI design, so we tried JQuery, YUI, and finally settled on ExtJS.  On another large project, we used Dojo.  And most recently, we convinced a large government client to switch (mid-stream) from Prototype to ExtJS.

YUI seemed like a dream at the time: nice widgets, clearly defined class hierarchy, good documentation, and quick to build an app.  When Yahoo! released a new version that was not backward compatible, I never used YUI again.

I suggest Dojo is good for people who like JSPs.  Controls are woven into HTML and processed by "the Dojo engine" on the client to create JavaScript widgets.  Documentation was woeful (and often not available).  An extension provided declarative AOP - really cool!

JQuery is great - wonderfully designed and fun to use.  I still use JQuery "underneath" ExtJS.

However, I nominate ExtJS as king.  This framework is art; a wonderfully thought-out class hierarchy, object-oriented design (sans abstraction), a rich set of low level utilities, cross-browser support, very nice documentation (available for download), incorporation of proven design patterns (e.g. Template, Observer), and a set of UI widgets that stack up to any.  The characteristic I like most about ExtJS is it makes me a better UI designer.  I am not a graphic artist, yet I can create very attractive web-apps (albeit not art), quickly and easily.  If you use only one framework, use ExtJS.

But why use only one?  See dateJS and flot.

Answer (score 0):

The beta version of Raxan might not be suitable for a serious project but the framework is growing and should be out of beta soon. While some parts of the framework are stable enough, other parts might not be so stable. You will have to build and test the app as you go along.

You can check out the latest beta 3 release: http://raxanpdi.com/

PS. Feel free to post your questions and suggestions on the forum